# meteor app with datatables how to enable row selection

Tags: meteor, datatables

I'm adding data tables to my meteor app.
I have never worked with the data tables library before. I would like to know the syntax to specify options to allow a table row to be selected. Also, it would be great to learn how to respond to the row selection event and to capture which row was selected, so I could use that row data in my app logic

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on the author's Web site:
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_single_row.html